# MVC seperate prjects for models, BLL, DAL, site using EF6

Tags: architecture, asp.net-mvc-5, data-access-layer

I'm having trouble separating the models and using EF6 in the DAL, i have created the models from database first approach in the DAL and then copied them out into the models project.

How do i configure the DAL to use EF6 with these models in another project?

I'm trying to architect my solution like this:

MVC Layer (views, viewmodels, controllers)
 |
BLL 
 | 
DAL (EF6)

All projects need to have a reference to the entities project which holds the models

Answer (score 0):

ok, this was a simple fix in the end, here's how i did it:

in my entities project i created a database first data model (edmx file and models etc)

in my DAL project i simply had to reference the entities assembly and then in each repository file (class) that CRUDs data i needed to add a using statement at the top to bring the entities namespace in. here's a simple example:

```
using MySolution.Entities.Models;

namespace MySolution.DAL.Repository
{
    public class AccountDAL : IAccountRepository, IDisposable
    {
        private MyDataEntities context;

        public AccountDAL()
        {
            this.context = new MyDataEntities();
        }

        .....etc
```

really rather simple.